# SQL UPDATE TABLE COLUMN DEFAULT NULL QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, alter-table

I am trying to make a php script to update a table column structure.

```
Name                Type         Collation  Attributes      Null    Default
promotion_dt        date                                    No      0000-00-00
```

I want to update the structure to change Default to NULL, and seccond I want to replace all the 0000-00-00 data with NULL.

What would the sql_query be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to first alter the table to allow null, then change the default and last update the existing values that are equal to the default;

```
-- Set nullable and update the default
ALTER TABLE myTable CHANGE promotion_dt promotion_dt DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL;   

-- Update the old values to the new default
UPDATE myTable SET promotion_dt=NULL WHERE promotion_dt='0000-00-00';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY promotin_dt DATE DEFUALT NULL;
 UPDATE tbl SET primotion_dt = NULL WHERE promotin_dt = '0000-00-00';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that in 2 queries:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY promotion_dt date NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

followed by:

```
UPDATE mytable SET promotion_dt=NULL where promotion_dt="0000-00-00";
```

**NOTE:**

As I just learnt from Joachim's answer above, instead of `MODIFY` in the 1st query, we can also use `CHANGE`, keeping in mind that the two syntax es are:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
  | CHANGE [COLUMN] old_col_name new_col_name column_definition
        [FIRST|AFTER col_name]
  | MODIFY [COLUMN] col_name column_definition
        [FIRST | AFTER col_name]
```

that is, `CHANGE` allows to change even the column name, thereby **requiring two column names** whereas `MODIFY` keeps the **column name unchanged**.